How to fix compilation errors when upgrading Node.js from 10 to 22 in my project?
I am trying up update the node from 10 to 22 in my project and it gives compilation error as follows.
PS D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\src> npm run build

> Popeye-for-otw@3.0.0 build
> webpack -p --mode production --https false

Hash: 2d12da5aa2b9e3d8a7f0
Version: webpack 4.47.0
Time: 17943ms
Built at: 26/11/2024 4:58:35 pm
 29 assets
Entrypoint static/js/taskpane/taskpane = static/js/taskpane/taskpane.edc24e6c2c548678763b.js
Entrypoint static/js/fallback/fallback = static/js/fallback/fallback.43653455be015cd2faab.js
Entrypoint static/js/onsend/onsend = static/js/onsend/onsend.b5845d8d591b6170e9aa.js
Entrypoint static/js/displaydialog/errordialogboxv1 = static/js/displaydialog/errordialogboxv1.be8e20592f7cb610a62e.js
[0] ./src/taskpane/taskpane.ts 718 bytes {3} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[1] ./src/taskpane/fallbackauth/fallbackauth.ts 718 bytes {1} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[2] ./src/onsend/onsend.ts 718 bytes {2} [built] [failed] [1 error]
[3] ./src/utils/uiutils/displaydialog/displaydialog.ts 3.95 KiB {0} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./src/utils/uiutils/displaydialog/displaydialog.ts
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/ts-loader/index.js):
Error: Debug Failure. False expression: Non-string value passed to `ts.resolveTypeReferenceDirective`, likely by a wrapping package working with an outdated `resolveTypeReferenceDirectives` signature. This is probably not a problem in TS itself.
    at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirective (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:43500:18)
    at D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\servicesHost.js:373:77
    at D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\servicesHost.js:95:142
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at Object.resolveTypeReferenceDirectives (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\servicesHost.js:95:125)
    at actualResolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:119382:163)
    at resolveTypeReferenceDirectiveNamesWorker (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:119682:26)
    at processTypeReferenceDirectives (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:121185:31)
    at findSourceFileWorker (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:121070:21)
    at findSourceFile (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:120922:26)
    at processImportedModules (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:121331:25)
    at findSourceFileWorker (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:121076:17)
    at findSourceFile (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:120922:26)
    at D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:120871:85
    at getSourceFileFromReferenceWorker (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:120837:34)
    at processSourceFile (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:120871:13)
    at processRootFile (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:120672:13)
    at D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:119473:67
    at Object.forEach (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:181:30)
    at Object.createProgram (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:119473:16)
    at synchronizeHostData (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:169335:26)
    at Object.getProgram (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\typescript\lib\typescript.js:169449:13)
    at successfulTypeScriptInstance (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\instances.js:178:80)
    at Object.getTypeScriptInstance (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\instances.js:34:12)
    at Object.loader (D:\temp checkouts\Plugin\ep\Client\Source\node_modules\ts-loader\dist\index.js:17:41)

this is my tsconfig.json file
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": false,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "allowUnusedLabels": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": false,
    "noUnusedLocals": false,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "lib": ["es7", "dom"],
    "pretty": true,
    "typeRoots": ["node_modules/@types"]
  },
  "exclude": ["node_modules"],
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "buildOnSave": false
}

following are the dependencies of my project.
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.11.6",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.11.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.11.5",
    "@types/crypto-js": "^4.0.1",
    "@types/debug": "^4.1.5",
    "@types/find-process": "1.2.0",
    "@types/office-js": "^1.0.394",
    "@types/office-runtime": "^1.0.35",
    "@types/react": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.3.1",
    "@types/webpack": "^4.4.34",
    "@types/webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.6",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^6.1.1",
    "css-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "eslint-config-office-addins": "^1.0.19",
    "eslint-plugin-office-addins": "^0.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.16.0",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "4.0.0-beta.0",
    "file-loader": "^4.2.0",
    "find-process": "^1.4.3",
    "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^4.5.0",
    "less": "^3.9.0",
    "less-loader": "^5.0.0",
    "office-addin-cli": "^1.0.13",
    "office-addin-debugging": "^5.0.5",
    "office-addin-dev-certs": "^1.5.5",
    "office-addin-lint": "^1.0.26",
    "office-addin-manifest": "^1.6.2",
    "office-addin-prettier-config": "^1.0.12",
    "postcss-loader": "3.0.0",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.4",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "ts-loader": "^6.2.2",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3",
    "webpack": "^4.43.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.12",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.11.0"
  },

I have tried upgrading ts-loader, typescript and webpack to the latest versions and also tried to comment out the whole displaydialog.ts file but nothing worked out. the same project compiles success fully when using node 10.
I am expecting to compile this project sucessfully with node 22.

What's the minimum I have to do to reproduce this problem?

You cannot blindly upgrade all the packages to the latest versions and expect everything to work out of the box. Most of the popular packages have migration guides. You need to follow their upgrade guidelines for each major version.
Old package versions generally are not forward compatible with nodejs, you need to upgrade each package individually.
Let's say that you have package Y with version 6.x.x. To update this package to 9, you first need to upgrade to 7, then 8, and lastly to 9 (step by step, and by applying their upgrade guidelines)
Edit: My advice is to not concentrate on the current error. Rollback all the package upgrades you made and upgrade them one by one. There can be functionality and code changes between each major upgrade which may cause unintended behaviors in your project.

I tried but couldn't find any migration guide for Node.js upgrades.

The versions I am using are not the latest versions. I have another project which runs with exact same version combination of these dependencies.

You should follow the migration guide for each dependency. Nodejs is the underlying engine, and you have nothing to do with it. Think about it this way: You are upgrading the engine of your car, but you first need to upgrade the components of your car.
